# Will Enumeration update? Java

Tags: java, enumeration

```
Tempest(Main.m.f.classIsDefault("Tempest"));

ClassType(something){}
```

This is in my enumeration class. Now im woundering if the enum will update every time something tries to reference it, so will it run Main.m.f.classIsDefault("Tempest") every time I reference the Tempest enum, or will it save the value it gets from when it loads?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Can you add some more code or details? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

No, an enum constant will never "update". All the values are initialized when the enum class is initialized, and never change subsequently. They are implemented as `static final` fields on the enum class.

Generally speaking, it should be safe to think of this code...

```
enum Foo {
    A(args...), B(args...);
}
```

...as being equivalent to the following code, except for the extra services that enum classes provide:

```
class Foo {
    static final Foo A = new Foo(args...):
    static final Foo B = new Foo(args...);
}
```